# Showing a default row dynamically with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having some issues trying to figure out how to show a default table row with jQuery. For example, I am using jQuery's `remove()` method to remove a table row but I am not sure on how to display a default table row if no entries are available to be shown. Here is my code:

```js
function deleteReport(id) {
   if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this row?")) {
     var parent = $('.reportTableData');

     $.post('includes/ajax/task_tracker_ajax.php', {
       action: 'delete_task',
       row_id: id
     }).done(function(data) {
       if (data == "deleted!") {
         var row = $('#tr_' + id);

         row.fadeOut('slow', function() {
           row.remove();
           return false;
         });

         // blah...
         if ($('.reportTableData tr td').html() == "") {
           parent.html("<tr><td class='cellStyleString' colspan='5' style='text-align: center;'>No tasks completed during this time range.</td></tr>");
         }
       }
     }).fail(function(data) {
       alert(data);
     });
   } else {
     return false;
   }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" class="reportTableData" style='width: 900px; margin-bottom: 20px;'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class='cellStyleTableHeaderDarkBlue' style='width: 100px; max-width: 100px;'>Name</th>
      <th class='cellStyleTableHeaderDarkBlue' style='width: 85px; max-width: 85px;'>Title</th>
      <th class='cellStyleTableHeaderDarkBlue'>Text</th>
      <th class='cellStyleTableHeaderDarkBlue' style='width: 120px; max-width: 120px;'>Date</th>
      <th class='cellStyleTableHeaderDarkBlue'>Report(s)</th>
      <th class='cellStyleTableHeaderDarkBlue'></th>
      <th class='cellStyleTableHeaderDarkBlue'></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="tr_id">
      <td id="row_id" class='cellStyleString'>name</td>
      <td contenteditable class='cellStyleString' id="title_id">title</td>
      <td contenteditable class='cellStyleString' id="text_id">text</td>
      <td contenteditable class='cellStyleString' id="insert_date_id">date</td>
      <td class='cellStyleString' id="reports_id">reports</td>
      <td class='cellStyleString'>
        <img src="images/edit_report.png" style="float: right;" id="edit_id" onclick="editReport('id');">
      </td>
      <td class="cellStyleString">
        <img src="images/x.png" style="float: right;" id="delete_id" onclick="deleteReport('id');">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing:

```
if ($('.reportTableData tr td').html() == "") {
    parent.html("<tr><td class='cellStyleString' colspan='5' style='text-align: center;'>No tasks completed during this time range.</td></tr>");
}
```

for:

```
if ($('.reportTableData tbody tr').length == 0) {
    parent.html("<tr><td class='cellStyleString' colspan='5' style='text-align: center;'>No tasks completed during this time range.</td></tr>");
}
```

should create the default row when you have removed all rows.

Comment: unfortunately it's not doing that :(

Comment: This means there's always a `tr` inside your `table`, even when you think there isn't. You'll need to place your code in https://jsfiddle.net/ for us to debug better.

Comment: yes, it is inside a php while loop, I was just wondering if I could get around this somehow

Comment: Oh, I see your HTML now. We should be counting `tr` inside `tbody` only. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: because all the <tr><td> tags are inside a while loop.

Comment: figured it out, it was needing to be set to 1 (the length, so if .length = 1. Thanks!